# Loading millions of metadata as a cache from BigQuery to enrich streaming events in Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, stream, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having the following use case: I'm streaming events from Kafka topics. My plan is read these events and for each one I need to enrich it with some metadata that exists in BigQuery. Let's assume I'm having millions of unique items, each one has its unique metadata stored in BigQuery. The metadata is being updated every 24h. In addition to this, my design requires developing a stateful pipeline, because I need to keep track of changes applied to these items for at least 24h since the item has arrived. So I understand that using fixed windows is not an option since the state is fixed per key per window.

In a later phase, I should do the same for some other BQ tables that are being updated in different times.

Here is what I tried to implement

My first approach is to use the slowly-changing lookup cache pattern: streaming the Kafka topic events, while loading the BQ metadata every 24h using an event trigger. I tested this approach, while it increases the memory usage since the metadata is being holded in-memory, it provides a way to enrich the event. The issue I faced with this is when I trigger the metadata update, I can see from the logs that the metadata is being updated, however the job keeps using an old version of the cache. Here is the code I'm using:

```
with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

sideinput_thresholds = ( 
    pipeline
    |"Read Side input file base path from pubsub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(topic="topic")
    | "Side input fixed window with early trigger" >> WindowInto(
        GlobalWindows(),
        trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)),
        accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
    | "Pulling BQ thresholds" >> ParDo(PullBQThresholds())
    )

enriched_events = (
    pipeline
    | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=input_topic)
    | "Global window" >> WindowInto(GlobalWindows())
    | "Add timestamp to elements" >> ParDo(AddTimestamp())
    | "Enrich event" >> ParDo(EnrichSideInput(), pvalue.AsSingleton(sideinput_thresholds))
)
```

While investigating this issue, I found an answer that refers that the cache might take hours to be updated and anlternative is to use `CoGroupByKey` by turning the side input into a pcollection and do the cogrouping. My issue here is for my case I need to apply a global window because I need to keep track of the state in global window (an event might receive an update after 18h of its ingestion). And in the documentation, I can see that `If you are using unbounded PCollections, you must use either non-global windowing or an aggregation trigger in order to perform a CoGroupByKey.` My question here is, can an unbounded pcollection with a global window be cogrouped by key with a side input that keeps being updated every 24h which holds millions of metadata?

Are there any other ways to implement a solution for this issue? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: By running a quick test, it appears that I cannot use the CoGRoupByKey for global windows

Comment: For the first part, a new Enrichment transform is included in Beam 2.54.0 (will release soon). Although we have just a BigTable handler, we plan to support BigQuery in future. I should have a post out soon on how you can write a custom handler for Enrichment transform that might help you in the meanwhile.

here is the [staged webpage](https://apache-beam-website-pull-requests.storage.googleapis.com/30187/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/enrichment/index.html) if you are curious